# Zip file is still available for download even file is deleted at server folder

Tags: caching, deployment, iis-7, zip, delete-file

I have config a application reference to download folder in IIS 7 (Window server 2008) to allow user download zip file. But when I delete or update file, the user still download this file at this time it has not been deleted or modified.

Any body meet the same situation with me? Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out a solution for this question. Very easy, just add "?v=" to the end of download link.